# Iteração em listas Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, loop, recursão

Alguém poderia me ajudar com este problema:
Faça um programa que receba números inteiros do usuário enquanto ele não digitar ”s”, sem
aspas, a seguir leia mais um número inteiro m e faça uma nova lista onde o elemento da posição i é dado pela soma dos elementos da lista original nas posições cujo resto da divisão do índice por m seja i. Por
fim, imprima a lista obtida.
Meu código ficou assim:

```
lista = []
lista2 = []

while True:
    n = input('Digite um número: ')
    if n == 's':
        break
    lista.append(int(n))
print(lista)

m = int(input('Digite um número: '))
for i in range(0, m):
    if i % m == i:
        lista[i] += lista[i] 
        lista2.append(lista[i])
print(lista2)
```

Não consigo pensar numa forma de fazer essa adição dos elementos de índice i com resto m. Por favor, se alguém puder me dar uma força, estou tentando faz um tempo já. Desde já agradeço.

Comment: quando o index vai ser igual ao resto da divisão dele mesmo por outro número? isso me confundiu muito! exemplo: quando 7 / x vai sobrar 7? se x for 0 a conta não é válida e se for 1 não tem sobra! não entendi qdo isso será validado

Answer (score 1):

## Teoria

Para entender melhor o problema, vamos considerar uma lista `A` qualquer de 10 elementos, com índices indo de 0 a 9, como apresentado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vamos também supor que o valor `m` lido posteriormente seja 3, assim, a lista que devemos formar será:

- O primeiro elemento, de índice 0, deve ser a soma de todos os valores de `A` em que o resto de divisão do índice nessa lista pelo valor de `m` é 0; sendo que os índices de `A` vão de 0 a 9, temos:

  - 0 % 3 = 0, então deve ser somado;
  - 1 % 3 = 1, então NÃO deve ser somado;
  - 2 % 3 = 2, então NÃO deve ser somado;
  - 3 % 3 = 0, então deve ser somado;
  - ...
- O segundo elemento, de índice 1, deve ser a soma de todos os valores de `A` em que o resto de divisão do índice nessa lista pelo valor de `m` é 1;
- O terceiro elemento, de índice 2, deve ser a soma de todos os valores de `A` em que o resto de divisão do índice nessa lista pelo valor de `m` é 2;
- É matematicamente impossível obtermos um resultado 3 para a operação x % 3 independente do valor de x; o que nos dá a informação de que sempre a lista a ser gerada possuirá exatos `m` elementos.

Desta forma, a lista gerada será, considerando as considerações acima:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## Código em Python

Abstraindo essa lógica para o Python, temos:

```py
numbers = []

# Lê os números enquanto não for informado a letra s
while (number := input('Digite um número ou "s" para encerrar: ')) != 's':
  numbers.append( int(number) )

m = int(input('Digite o valor de m: '))

# Gera a nova lista
result = [
  sum(number for k, number in enumerate(numbers) if k % m == i)
  for i in range(m)
]

# Exibe o resultado
print(result)
```

## Validação da solução

Considerando que sejam informados os valores de 0 a 9 para a lista, com o m valendo 3, teríamos:

```py
numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
m = 3
```

Dadas as regras da lista gerada, podemos defini-la como:

```py
result = [
  0 + 3 + 6 + 9,  # 18
  1 + 4 + 7,      # 12
  2 + 5 + 8       # 15
]
```

Ao executar o código supracitado come essas entradas, temos o resultado `[18, 12, 15]`, como esperado (https://ideone.com/1APzEc).

## E o seu código?

```py
lista = []
lista2 = []

while True:
    n = input('Digite um número: ')
    if n == 's':
        break
    lista.append(int(n))
print(lista)

m = int(input('Digite um número: '))
for i in range(0, m):
    if i % m == i:
        lista[i] += lista[i] 
        lista2.append(lista[i])
print(lista2)
```

Podemos listar:

- O laço de repetição para ler os valores e parar quando digitado "s" está correto;
- Leitura do valor de `m` está correto;

Então vamos focar na lógica de calcular a nova lista.

```py
for i in range(0, m):
    if i % m == i:
        lista[i] += lista[i] 
        lista2.append(lista[i])
```

Você está percorrendo, no primeiro laço de repetição, os valores de 0 a  `m-1`, devido à função `range`, o que está correto, pois gerará `m` valores na lista final, que é o esperado, como vimos na teoria.

O problema começou quando fez `if i % m == i`. A ideia até parece correta, mas o valor de `i` é igual dos dois lados da comparação, então não faz sentido, uma vez que só será `True` se `i` valer 0. O correto é que, como vimos também na teoria, que o primeiro `i` na verdade fosse o índice da lista original, o que nos leva ao segundo problema:

Você não iterou a lista original. Faltou um novo laço de repetição que iterasse a lista original para avaliar cada índice. Algo como:

```py
for i in range(0, m):
  for k in range(0, len(lista)):
    if k % m == i:
      ...
```

Após isso, você fez `lista[i] += lista[i]`, o que também não faz sentido, pois está somando o valor de `lista[i]` nele mesmo, duplicando-o, sendo que `i`, nesse ponto, nem é o índice da lista original, então nem faz sentido acessar `lista[i]`. Agora temos o índice `k` que é da lista original e é esse valor que devemos acumular:

```py
for i in range(0, m):
  soma = 0
  for k in range(0, len(lista)):
    if k % m == i:
      soma += lista[k]
```

E, por fim, adicionar o valor acumulado na lista final:

```py
for i in range(0, m):
  soma = 0
  for k in range(0, len(lista)):
    if k % m == i:
      soma += lista[k]
  lista2.append(soma)
```

Então o seu código corrigido seria (ignorando a parte da leitura para simplificar):

```py
lista = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
lista2 = []
m = 3

for i in range(0, m):
  soma = 0
  for k in range(0, len(lista)):
    if k % m == i:
        soma += lista[k] 
  lista2.append(soma)
```

Que é equivalente ao que eu propus como solução, porém não tão idiomático (fazer uso da linguagem ao seu favor).